# Optimization of Laravel pivot table relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a pivot table called `invite_riskarea` which is designed as follows:

[image]

This table handles the permissions that have a specific user (through an invite id) to access to specific riskfields. Each riskfield is associated with a riskarea which acts as the main container of specific riskfields.

Within the model `Invite` I have this relationship:

```
public function riskareas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Riskarea::class)->withPivot('riskfield_id', 'insert', 'edit', 'view');
}
```

In this way I can return all the riskareas associated with a specific invite, and I should be able to return all the riskfields associated with a specific riskarea in the same invite model.

As you can see from the table `invite_riskarea`, I have three columns called `insert`, `edit`, and `delete`. These columns manage the types of permissions assigned to a specific user (via an invite id) for a specific riskfield belonging to a riskarea.

I'm trying to retrieve the riskarea permission in the following way:

```
$invite = Invite::where('id', 58)->first();
$riskarea = $invite->riskareas[0];
$riskfield = $riskareas->riskfields[0];
echo 'view permission => ' . $riskfield->insert;
```

The problem's that I'm not able to setup a correct relationship in the `Invite` model that returns me the pivot data of the permissions columns only for the `riskfield` associated with the `riskarea`.

So I have manage to handle this situation in this way:

```
$riskareas = Riskarea::all();

foreach ($riskareas as &$riskarea) {
    foreach ($riskarea->riskfields as &$riskfield) {
        $result = DB::table('invite_riskarea')
            ->select('insert', 'edit', 'view')
            ->where([
                'riskarea_id' => $riskarea->id,
                'riskfield_id' => $riskfield->id
            ])
            ->first();

        if ($result) {
            $riskfield->insert = $result->insert;
            $riskfield->edit = $result->edit;
            $riskfield->view = $result->view;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I get all the riskareas, and then I iterate over the riskfields associated. For each riskfield, I get the permissions in the `invite_riskarea` table and then I have the correct structure that I want.

So to summarize:

1. Is it actually possible create a model relationship that returns the permissions for riskfield and not for riskarea?
2. Is my table implementation good enough to handle that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I suggest you define back the many-to-many relation for the Riskfield model  with the Invite model.

   You can also define a direct many-to-many relationship with riskfield in the Invite model. This is how convenient it is for you personally.

   And so the inverse many-to-many relationship

   ```
   public function invites()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Invite::class)->withPivot('insert', 'edit', 'view');
   }
   ```

   Then get all objects' Riskfields that are associated with the specified invite:

   ```
    $riskfields = Riskfields::wherehas('invites' . function (Builder $query) use ($invite_id) {
        $query->where('invites.id', $invite_id);
    })->with('invites')->get();
   ```

   Then you can access the desired fields of the pivot table in the specified way:

   ```
    foreach ($riskfields as $riskfield) {
        foreach ($riskfield->invites as $invite) {
            $insertRiskField = $invite->pivot->insert;
            $editRiskField = $invite->pivot->edit;
            $viewRiskField = $invite->pivot->view;
        }
    }
   ```

   Eager loading executes one query to the database
2. Yes

   [Documentation Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer. May I ask if would be possible get an example of eloquent based on the loop I wrote: get all riskareas from the riskareas table and their associated riskfields from the riskfields table, so the invite relationship can return me the riskareas with the riskfields that have permissions for that specific invite.  it would be possible?

Comment: If your invite model defines many-to-many relationships with the riskfield and riskarea tables, then you can access them through an invite like this: `Invite::with('riskfields', 'riskareas')->whereId($invite_id)->get();` Then access the pivot table through the dynamic property of the pivots of these dependencies ('riskfields', 'riskareas')

There is another option, but I do not recommend it. However, if you want, then it can be
`Riskare::whereHas('invites', function(Builder $query use($id)){$query->where('invite.id',$id)})->with('riskfields.inviteriskareas')->all();`

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I'm thinking another way and I would like to have your opinion about that. What about if I retrieve all the `riskareas` and then when I iterate over the `riskfields` associated to the riskarea, I check if the `riskfield` has a permission querying the table `invite_riskfield`? Do you think it's a good approach? It would be similar to the `hasRole` method of `laratrust` package. I just need to figure out how to implement this, may you could give me an help?